# MySql filter enum value with Where clause

Tags: mysql

In database i have enum column where i store this values:

```
ClassName                         
----------------------------------
Page                              
DFM\BlogCategory                  
DFM\BlogPage                      
DFM\HomePage                      
DFM\PostPage                      
DFM\Product                       
DFM\ProductCategory               
DFM\ShopPage                      
SilverStripe\ErrorPage\ErrorPage
```

When i try to show all rows `WHERE ClassName='DFM\Product'` i get 0 results. But tere is 3 records.
When i try to this `WHERE ClassName='Page'` this work.

Why when i pass value in WHere clause value in `namespace` format i dont get result?

[image]

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for your table, sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows), query text which (as you suggest) must, but does not return the row(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if there is a problem with \ or try used the function `trim` and `replace`,there may be a space in the record.

example:

```
WHERE trim(ClassName)='DFM\Product'
```

or

```
WHERE REPLACE(ClassName,' ','')='DFM\Product'

WHERE REPLACE(ClassName,'\','')=Replace('DFM\Product','\','')
```

Comment: In string literal the slash must be simply doubled. I.e. not `'DFM\Product'` but `'DFM\\Product'`.